# Error expected primary-expression before 'int'

Tags: c++, funciones, dev-c++, parametros

estoy intentando retornar parametros pasando la ubicacion de las variables

```
int promsistolica(int& total4, int& total5, int& total6){

//  int total4, total5, total6;

    int promesistolica;

    promesistolica = (total4 + total5 + total6) / 3;

    cout<<"el promedio de la presion sistolica en mmhg ";

    cout<<promesistolica;
    
    return promesistolica;
    
}
```

cuando hago la llamada de funcion toda ese parte no se ejecuta

```
int main(){

    cout<<"Bienvendio a su centro de salud virtual para la presion \n";

    cout<<"registre su presion alterial de cada dia de la semana  ";
    cout<<endl;

    diastolicamanana();

    diastolicatarde();

    diastolicanoche();

    promdiastolica(int& total1, int& total2, int& total3);

    sistolicamanana();

    sistolicatarde();

    sistolicanoche();

    promsistolica(int& total4, int& total5,int& total6);

    evaluarpresion(int&, int&);
    
}
```

Me sale este error:

> caso practico c++\caso practico16.cpp [Error] expected primary-expression before 'int'

pero segun ya he declarado todo

Comment: Las llamadas a funciones son diferentes a las definiciones de funciones, para llamar a `promdiastolica` debes escribir `promdiastolica(total1, total2, total3);`

Answer (score 3):

### Primero:

Para poder pasarle esos parámetro a la función, los debiste de haber definido e inicializado en tu `main()`.

En la llamada a la función en esta parte:

```
promdiastolica(int& total1, int& total2, int& total3);
```

No es necesario poner el `int&` porque no estas declarando la función, sólo la estás llamando así que reemplaza esa línea por:

```
promdiastolica(total1, total2, total3);
```

Haz lo mismo en la línea que muestro a continuación:

```
promsistolica(int& total4, int& total5,int& total6);
```

Y en:

```
evaluarpresion(int&, int&);
```

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta márcala con el Check  :)